# The QProgressDialog is not closing

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I'm having some trouble with a **QProgressDialog** on my app.

When the user clicks on a calculation button, I show a **QProgressDialog** that is updated from a **QThread** (I don't think this is related to the problem), and when this **QThread** finishes I call a function that closes the **QProgressDialog**.

```
progressDialog->setValue(100);
progressDialog->close();
```

It seems to be working.

But if the user clicks on the calculation button and minimizes the app (main window), the **QProgressDialog** don't close:

[image]

I already checked and the code is reaching on the command:

```
progressDialog->close();
```

I don't know what is happening, can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following attribute to my progress dialog:

```
progressDialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
```